# Button.Container is null after adding the button to the FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, windows, forms, .net-4.8

I am creating an application that adds buttons to a tab view with each tab having a different FlowLayoutPanel. Each button has a ContextMenuStrip added to it. Here is the problem: in the MenuStrip's onclick function I'm trying to access the button's container but it returns null. The reason is that after removing the task from the list I want to remove the button from the FlowLayoutPanel. This wasn't an issue in the version of the app without tab view and only a single FlowLayoutPanel. So my question is, what am I missing or doing wrong?

Below are two methods responsible for adding and configuring the button, as well as one method that is called on user clicking the menu item in ContextMenuStrip.

```
public void LoadTaskToFlowPanel(UserTask task)
        {
            FlowLayoutPanel targetFlowLayoutPanel = GetTargetFlowLayoutPanel(task);

            if (task == null || targetFlowLayoutPanel == null)
                return;

            Button b = new Button();
            targetFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(b);

            b.Text = task.TaskName + "\n" + task.Deadline.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            b.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            b.Name = task.TaskId.ToString();
            b.Size = new Size(400, 75);
            b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            b.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
            b.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.DimGray;

            if (task.TaskPriority == UserTask.Priority.High)
            {
                b.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 227, 80, 89);
            }

            if (task.TaskPriority == UserTask.Priority.Medium)
            {
                b.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 253, 213, 12);
            }

            if (task.TaskPriority == UserTask.Priority.Low)
            {
                b.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 47, 172, 102);
            }

            Image statusIcon = GetImageForStatusIcon(task.TaskStatus);
            if (statusIcon != null)
            {
                b.Image = statusIcon;
                b.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.TextBeforeImage;
                b.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            }

            b.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

            b.Click += delegate (Object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ViewEditTask viewOrEditTask = new ViewEditTask(ref task, task.TaskStatus == UserTask.Status.Completed ? false : true, ref b, this);
                viewOrEditTask.Show();
            };

            b.ContextMenuStrip = tasksToolsStrip;
        }
```

```
private FlowLayoutPanel GetTargetFlowLayoutPanel(UserTask task)
        {
            if (task.TaskStatus == UserTask.Status.NotCompleted)
                return failedTasksLayoutPanel;

            if (task.TaskStatus == UserTask.Status.Completed)
                return completedTasksFlowPanel;

            if (task.TaskStatus == UserTask.Status.InProgress
                && task.Deadline.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
                return todaysTasksFlowPanel;

            if (task.TaskStatus == UserTask.Status.InProgress
                && task.Deadline.Date >= Utilities.GetStartOfTheWeek().Date
                && task.Deadline.Date <= Utilities.GetEndOfTheWeek().Date)
                return currentWeekTasksFlowPanel;

            return null;
        }
```

```
private void deleteTaskTool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
            ContextMenuStrip contextMenu = (ContextMenuStrip)menuItem.Owner;
            Button button = (Button)contextMenu.SourceControl;
            FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel = button.Container as FlowLayoutPanel;

            MessageBox.Show("Is Button's container null? " + (button.Container == null));
            //flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(button);
            //int.TryParse(button.Name, out int removeId);
            //UserTask taskToRemove = TaskManager.Instance.Tasks.Find(task => task.TaskId == removeId);
            //TaskManager.Instance.Tasks.Remove(taskToRemove);
            //DisplayStats();
        }
```

On top of that, if you have any tips regarding the readability of the code, or tips how to improve my coding, feel free to comment on it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: [The `Component.Container` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component.container?view=net-7.0) (which is inherited by `Button`) concerns _ye olde_ `IContainer` from COM and OLE, and is entirely unrelated to a WinForms Control's parent control: for that, use `Control.Parent`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.parent?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. But then I'm wondering why using the Container worked without TabView?

Comment: Your `LoadTaskToFlowPanel` method will fail if `UserTask task` is `null` because `` always calls `GetTargetFlowLayoutPanel` first, which does not check if `task == null`, so if `task` is `null` then `GetTargetFlowLayoutPanel`'s first line will cause a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Some, but not all, WinForms Controls _do_ update a Control's `.Container`, but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: That point about calling GetTargetFlowLayoutPanel before checking if task is null, is a great spot too, thanks